# how do you redirect to a page as soon as a user enables their javascript?

Tags: javascript, redirect

i was wondering if there was some sort of event triggered when javascript is enabled in a browser (ie. in firefox, tools->options->check off enable javascript-> click ok). i want to redirect a user to a page when this happens. any ideas?

Thanks!

EDIT:
i've put an iframe into the page but am not getting the alert (after i enable javascript), so the refresh must not be working. what is wrong with this?

```
    <iframe style="display:none">
        <html>
            <head>
                <title>my iframe</title>

                <meta http-equiv="Refresh" content="5" />

                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.parent.location.href = 'home.php';
                    alert("HELLO");
                </script>

            </head>
        </html>
    </iframe>
```

Comment: Why can't you server-side redirect?

Comment: because i don't know if they have JS enabled server-side

Comment: I'm not sure why you want to do this, but I suspect it's for the purposes of evil.  Should you be forcing users to enable JavaScript when they don't want to?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can only detect whether JavaScript is enabled/disabled on page load. There is no event called for it being enabled/disabled after a page has loaded. Only possible solution i can think is to have an invisible iframe in your main page containing a script with a small meta refresh and a check for whether JavaScript is enabled - if it is then redirect the parent(main) page.

so your iframe would include something like this:

***jscheck.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>my iframe</title>
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5">
<script type="text/javascript">
window.parent.location.href = 'js_turned_on.html';
</script>
</head>
<body>
</body>
</html>
```

***checker.html***

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<iframe src="jscheck.html"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: this is good too! i'll have to try this out and see if it works, because it is better than refreshing the entire page rather than an invisible iframe. thanks!

Comment: @Garrett - the iframe needs to link to an actual file using its src attribute - see example above

Comment: thanks a lot! i've never used an iframe before. this is actually amazing! good thinking, seengee!

Answer (score 5):

not realy a good ide, but i think it would work:

- set a meta-refresh of 5(?) seconds on your first page and:
- set a javascript-redirect to your second page (window.location.href='...')

as long as javascript is disabled, the user stays on page1, where every 5 seconds the refresh is triggered... if javascript gets enabled, on the next refresh the js-redirect is done so the user gets to page2.

Comment: yes but if not the user is stuck on a page which reloads every 5 seconds!

Comment: if i understand the question correct, page1 is only a "please enable scripts, dude!"-page, where there is no problem with a 5-second-refresh

Comment: maybe yeah, nothing in the question to actually suggest that is the case though.

Comment: good idea! maybe instead of 5 seconds i'll do 60 seconds so they have a chance to read and follow the instructions on how to enable javascript. thanks!

Comment: @seengee: but nothing suggests it's a complex page where you can't do so, too, so i expected easy conditions

Comment: @oezi true - both solutions would work but i still prefer mine :p

Answer (score 0):

you could have a small timer on your page with a 1 second time out.

Comment: but how do i know when javascript is enabled? will all <script> tags run automatically?